# netebeans: xdebug doesn't stop on breakpoints on browser refresh

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

I must say that you, the stack overflow community have been a big help so far, but recently I came across a problem I fail to solve even by googling it.

my environment:
- arch linux with KDE desktop environment:
- apache 2.2.25-1
- php 5.5.3
- xdebug 2.2.3-3
- netbeans 7.3.1

So, I have been using xdebug on netbeans for 2 months or so without problem. recently it started causing me problems:

> I run the debug session, netbeans stops on all breakpoints - fine.
>   on clicking run (f6) it reruns and also stops on breakpoints. so I'm
>   guessing xdebug is configured OK.
>  but:
>  if I refresh the
>   website in the browser(like I used to do all the time), netbeans
>   doesn't stop on breakpoints. This used to work, a week ago just fine.

The only change I noticed was a message popping up when I run the debug session. first saying:"localhost contacted waiting for reply". That's when it stops on a breakpoint. After passing breakpoints it concludes the popup with [Finished] tag. As if the xdebug stopped. In netbeans though I can still see the xdebug-session running. This message wasn't there when things worked fine.

I hope this is enough information. If you need any extra information, I'll be glad to oblige.

edit:
Possible workaround:
installed easy Xdebug addon in firefox. Now it works on page refresh and on form submit, same as before the problems began.